# PHPExcel unknown characters

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I've followed some tutorials and saw some people with same issue but I can't figure out how to put this working on my project.

Btw, I'm using CodeIgniter framework and I have Excel 2007 in my computer.

```
public function exportExcel(){

    require(APPPATH . 'libraries/toExcel/PHPExcel.php');
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello');

    // Rename worksheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');     

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=01simple.xls');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter->save('php://output');

    exit;
}
```

This is my code just for testings. Whenever I download the file generated by that function and try to open it is this what I get:
[image]

And when I click "Yes" I receive this:

[image]

Comment: Make sure that nothing is sent to the browser other than the save to php://output.... make sure that no whitespace characters are sent, no newlines or any markup..... make sure that anything CI might send is suppressed/turned off.... open the file in a text editor, and look for any leading/training whitespace characters, or any obvious plaintext messages, or any html markup

Comment: I have a blank space as the first character how can I get rid of this? I tried Linesofcode's solutions but it didnt work, I have also checked any other outputs but no success

Comment: @DIEGOF.G. have you tried `trim`?

Comment: @Linesofcode what would I trim ?

Comment: @DIEGOF.G. nvm, thought you were talking about some variable or something, but if you get an blank space as the first character you need to go step-by-step until you find it.

Comment: @Linesofcode I've done it, but still I didn't have this error before, I solved by putting ob_start(); in my __construct function and right before $writer->save('php://output'); I added ob_end_clean();
    ob_get_clean();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solved.**

```
ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Answer (score 0):

All php_excel changed Unknown Creator worksheet.
directory application/third_party/phpexcel/PHPExcel/DocumentProperties.php
changed line 43;

```
private $creator = 'Unknown Creator'; changed ↓
private $creator = 'your name';
```